# Editing /etc/init.d/mysql to remove mysql.sock automatically

Tags: shell-script, centos, mysql

I am running MySQL on a CentOS release 6.5 (Final) virtual machine. It is used for testing Joomla.

The phyiscal host reboots frequently, which is fine. The VM, however, does not perform a clean shutdown. When it reboots there is a lock file here: `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`

I built a shell script that will remove it for me that i currently execute manually. This works perfectly well but requires that i run it.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mv /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock.bak
sudo service mysqld restart
```

It was suggested to me that I edit the /etc/init.d/mysql to automatically remove the lock file for me. While this seems like a good idea the lock file does perform a valuable purpose and to tamper with that im mysqld might be more harmful that good.

What can i do to remove the lock file automatically after a reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket file is a way for processes to communicate with the running server.  When the server is dead, there is no need for the socket. As you said, it would have been removed if the server had a chance to shutdown gracefully. MySQL fails to start if the socket is already there; hence the error message. Removing it, when a server isn't running, is fine.

Edit `/etc/init.d/mysql` and find the line:

```
start(){
```

Insert the following below it:

```
if [ -S /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock ] ; then
    rm /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
fi
```

So that it look like the following:

```
start(){
        if [ -S /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock ] ; then
            rm /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
        fi
```

Comment: Note: I haven't an installation of MySQL running using `initd` therefore can't confirm the above works, but is should.  Let me know what it does so that I can edit the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I would add those lines to /etc/inittab

That file runs at every boot.

you can leave off the sudo and the restart.

Make "damn sure" that /etc/inittab returns 0